# Heroku H31 errors on production, 'upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header' - Is this an 'us' or 'them' proplem?

Tags: heroku, response-headers

Hosting a rails web app on heroku; no recent code changes but about 2 days ago the application started reporting constant H31 misdirect errors.  After looking into the documentation, since the application was still accessible I moved on.
The next day users from some of the subdomains could not access the application while others could.  The application uses a wildcard certificate and we are behind a WAF.  The first thing I tried was checking firewall logs and nothing was showing as blocked.  I turned off the firewall and connected the domain directly to the application and still received the H31 stream, after 15 minutes of no change i re-enabled the firewall.
Reached out to the firewall and they said that their logs only showed `upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header`
At this point they suggested the issue was most likely on the Heroku DNS servers, so I'm waiting for a response at this point.

Is there anything I can do in the heroku environment that would change this or am I stuck waiting for a response?

Comment: what is your DNS provider? PointDNS by chance?

Comment: Switching to DNSSimple seems to have helped - still propegating and still getting some H31s, but much less than before.